# React ref and ref.current are returning different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I got a problem when I can't access real value of a ref created via react useRef hook.

So I have a `const st = useRef(state);` and inside of it there is an object with some keys and values.

I also have a `useEffect` hook that updates the reference for `st.current`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  st.current = value
}, [value])
```

So when I am doing a `console.log` of the `st` variable it shows me an object with a `current` key and its value is a real time reference for the object I am putting into st.current and all the values inside are correct.

But when I am trying to `console.log` the `st.current` itself it shows me the previous state of the object. And also when I am trying to access any of the variables inside the `st.current` it returns the previous value :(

This is the code example. **Pay your attention on selectedFolders key**. It shows different values for the same object.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post images of code.

Comment: May be a cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chrome-s-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-objects

Comment: @BrianThompson thank you, this is it.